# HTML video tag - change source on viewport without media attribute

Tags: html, reactjs, video, responsive, viewport

I'm trying to implement a video in HTML with react. So if the viewport is under 750px width, I would like to change the video source to a smaller resolution/ smaller file (because of high data transfer and so on).

So in a perfect HTML world, you would build this:

```html
<video controls> 
   <source src="video-small.mp4" type="video/mp4" media="all and (max-width: 750px)"> 
   <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
</video>
```

Since `media` is not (or no more) [specified in the source tag if it's inside of a video ta](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source)g, I can't use this anymore. Because Chrome is displaying the first source, which is the mobile video. No matter if desktop or mobile.

**Second solution** was to wrap a container around and set `display: none;` to the not visible video:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import LazyLoad from 'react-lazyload'

const MobileVideo = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  display: none;
  ${({theme}) => theme.media.mobile`
    display: block;
  `}
`

const DesktopVideo = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  display: block;
  ${({theme}) => theme.media.mobile`
    display: none;
  `}
`

const VideoComponent = ({
  srcWebm,
  srcMp4,
  mobileSrcWebm,
  mobileSrcMp4,
  poster,
  className,
  forwardedRef,
  ...rest
}) => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <MobileVideo>
      <video
        playsInline
        poster={poster.url}
        className={className}
        ref={forwardedRef}
        {...rest}
      >
        {mobileSrcWebm.url !== '' && (
          <source src={mobileSrcWebm.url} type="video/webm" />
        )}
        {mobileSrcMp4.url !== '' && (
          <source src={mobileSrcMp4.url} type="video/mp4" />
        )}
      </video>
    </MobileVideo>
    <DesktopVideo>
      <video
        playsInline
        poster={poster.url}
        className={className}
        ref={forwardedRef}
        {...rest}
      >
        {srcWebm.url !== '' && <source src={srcWebm.url} type="video/webm" />}
        {srcMp4.url !== '' && <source src={srcMp4.url} type="video/mp4" />}
      </video>
    </DesktopVideo>
  </React.Fragment>
)
```

In this case the correct video is displayed, but both videos are downloaded (in Chrome). Hiding doesn't prevent the browser from downloading. SAD!

**Third solution** was to use the second solution and remove the invisible component from the DOM:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import LazyLoad from 'react-lazyload'

import {sizes} from '../../lib/ThemeProvider/media'

const MobileVideo = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  display: none;
  ${({ theme }) => theme.media.mobile`
    display: block;
  `}
`

const DesktopVideo = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  display: block;
  ${({ theme }) => theme.media.mobile`
    display: none;
  `}
`

class VideoComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    showMobileSrc: true
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.resize()
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.resize)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.resize)
  }

  resize = () => {
    if (window.innerWidth >= sizes.mobile) {
      this.setState({ showMobileSrc: false })
    } else {
      this.setState({ showMobileSrc: true })
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { srcWebm,
      srcMp4,
      mobileSrcWebm,
      mobileSrcMp4,
      poster,
      className,
      forwardedRef,
      ...rest
    } = this.props
    const {showMobileSrc} = this.state
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {showMobileSrc && <MobileVideo>
          <video
            playsInline
            poster={poster.url}
            className={className}
            ref={forwardedRef}
            {...rest}
          >
            {mobileSrcWebm.url !== '' && (
              <source src={mobileSrcWebm.url} type="video/webm" />
            )}
            {mobileSrcMp4.url !== '' && (
              <source src={mobileSrcMp4.url} type="video/mp4" />
            )}
          </video>
        </MobileVideo>}
        {!showMobileSrc && <DesktopVideo>
          <video
            playsInline
            poster={poster.url}
            className={className}
            ref={forwardedRef}
            {...rest}
          >
            {srcWebm.url !== '' && <source src={srcWebm.url} type="video/webm" />}
            {srcMp4.url !== '' && <source src={srcMp4.url} type="video/mp4" />}
          </video>
        </DesktopVideo>}
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

But chrome is downloading both videos anyway. HTML seems to be correct. No idea what chrome is doing there..

First i really don"t understand why they removed the media attribute from the source tag inside of a video tag. Thats not consistently implemented.

Anyway: How can I change the source at a defined viewport width and prevent downloading both videos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple JavaScript solution (not ReactJS specific, but see [this component](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-media) for a pure ReactJS solution)

```
if (matchMedia) {
    var mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 600px)");
    mq.addListener(WidthChange);
}

function WidthChange(mq) {
    if (mq.matches) {
    // set source to desktop
    } else {
    // set source to mobile
}
}
```